# Returning a particular value for first occurence over multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have all my customers in column a and their orders stretching across columns to AB. The months are the columns. I am using the formula:

=INDEX(B177:AG177,(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B177:AG177<>0),0,0),0)))

This gives me the amount of their first order but I want it to return the value for the corresponding column and row 1 of the occurence so I can get the month and the year instead of the dollar amount.

Doing this will allow me to count how many new customers started each month. I've scoured the internet but can't find anything that works for me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I could not understand how the data is organized. Can you share your database?
Or even some pictures.

Comment: Maybe =INDEX(B1:AG1,(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B177:AG177<>0),0,0),0)))

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple. Swear I tried that. Thank you Charles.